# Bash equivalent of Windows' net helpmsg

Tags: bash, cmd

In a traditional Windows shell, I can use `net helpmsg` to get the string-based message from an exit status code.  For example, if I wanted to know what a status of 2 meant, I would do the following:

**INPUT COMMMAND:** `net helpmsg 2`

**OUTPUT:** `The system cannot find the file specified.`

I am wondering: is there an equivalent function in Bash (wherein I pass an error code and a string is returned)?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that have to be program-dependent? For example, `grep` returns `1` if it doesn't find any matches, whereas `diff` returns `1` if it finds differences. What could the message for `1` be that would cover both of these?

Comment: Which bash function do you use that returns a number as an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides `perror`, which handles OS and MySQL error codes.

```
$ perror 2
OS error code   2:  No such file or directory
```

Comment: I didn't even know this existed - perfect!